# Can I build only the Opencv_contrib extra modules with prebuilt libraries of OpenCV 3.0.0?

Tags: opencv3.0

I am using opencv 3.0.0 libraries for an object tracking project for which I need the SURF class functions and interfaces. 
I recently learnt that it is now in the opencv_contrib module that needs to be added to the opencv libraries. I have the following questions:

1) Is it possible to build only this module into my existing opencv libraries that I extracted using the opencv.exe downloaded directly form their website (I did not build it using CMake the first time)

2) Is it ok to rebuild the entire opencv3.0.0 library with the extra modules and to keep the pre-built libraries in seperate directories?

3) If (2) is not possible, is there a way to erase all the opencv 3.0.0 library files and start fresh with extra modules included?

I am very new to this and I am using OpenCV to complete an assignment on object tracking.

Comment: 1) no, not possible. 2) yes(but you won't need them anymore) 3) don't worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No,its not possible. Try getting a git version of OpenCV3.0 and OpenCV_contrib3.0 and use Cmake to build it from the source.
2. Why do you want to keep the old pre-compiled files in a separate directory? 
   You cannot use it anyways.
3. Yes, you can do that. You can save some disk space if you delete the older ones.